# Add text to specific blocks defined by some special characters in sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have hundreds of books in text format, which will be converted to epub and pdf with pandoc. Each text file contains plain text and poems. Aligning poems is a repeated task. Every second line of each poem needs to be intended. I need to add some special character at every other line of each poem, say, `==`.

My question is:

```
here are some text  

poem line 1  
poem line 2  
poem line 3  
poem line 4  

here are some text

poem line 1  
poem line 2
```

I need output

```
here are some text  

poem line 1  
==poem line 2  

here are some text  

poem line 1  
==poem line 2  
poem line 3  
==poem line 4
```

My idea is:

If we define poem blocks by some special character like

```
~   
poem line 1  
poem line 2  
~~  

~  
poem line 1  
poem line 2  
poem line 3  
poem line 4  
~~
```

sed finds this `~` and adds `==` at each 3+2 lines and ended with `~~`.

output should like this

```
~   
poem line 1  
== poem line 2  
~~  

~  
poem line 1  
== poem line 2  
poem line 3  
== poem line 4  
~~
```

Is it possible to do with sed or awk or any other scripts?

http://xensoft.com/use-sed-to-insert-text-every-n-lines-characters/

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is not quite clear. Please do add condition by which lines will be inserted in your post with more clear examples and do let us know then.

Comment: Why did you flip the order of poems in your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '/^$/b;n;/^$/b;s/^/--/' input
```

- `/^$/b`: if the line is empty print it and start again with the next line.
- `n`: print current line and get the next one.
- `s/^/--/`: add special chars to the line.

Output:

```
here are some text  

poem line 1  
--poem line 2  
poem line 3  
--poem line 4  

here are some text

poem line 1  
--poem line 2
```

You can use delimiters as you suggested:

```
here are some text
@+
poem line 1  
poem line 2  
poem line 3  
poem line 4  
@-
here are some text
@+
poem line 1  
poem line 2 
poem line 3
@-
```

With this command:

```
sed '/@+/!b;:l;n;/@-/b;n;/@-/b;s/^/--/;bl;' input
```

You get:

```
here are some text
@+
poem line 1  
--poem line 2  
poem line 3  
--poem line 4  
@-
here are some text
@+
poem line 1  
--poem line 2 
poem line 3
@-
```

Comment: This is works.. but If plain line have line breaks those place also affects. Can we modified this command to only works with specific blocks defined by us..
like 

~   
poem line 1  
poem line 2   
~~
some text   
some other text  
~  
poem line 1    
poem line 2   
poem line 3   
poem line 4  
~~

sed find '~' and add until '~~'

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^~\s*$/{:a;n;/^~~\s*$/b;n;//b;s/^/== /;ba}' file
```

Insert `==` before the second line of each poem, where poems are delimited by `~` and `~~`.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for doing `s/old/new` on individual strings, **that is all**. This is a completely inappropriate task for sed, absolutely trivial for awk and exactly the type of task awk was created to perform, and you don't need to add additional `~` delimiters to your text to just get the output you posted from the first block of input you posted:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print (i%2?"":"==") $i; print ""}' file
here are some text

poem line 1
==poem line 2
poem line 3
==poem line 4

here are some text

poem line 1
==poem line 2
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Comment: for the record, sed does much more than search replace on individual strings.

Comment: It **can** do more but anything else hasn't been what you should use sed for since the mid-late 1970s when awk was invented. You **can** use a hammer to put all the nails in your house when building it but you'd get the job done much faster and with far less effort using a nailgun. All of the options that have been added to sed over the years to let it do more and more are the equivalent of turning a hammer into an electric hammer (https://gremlins.fandom.com/wiki/Electric_Hammer?file=Electric_Hammer.png) when there are much better tools readily available - a cute mental exercise but thats all